# Making a mob-like decision tree with pre-specified splits and models for leaves

Tags: r, modeling, predictive-models, cart

I would like to make a special kind of hybrid tree model in R, similar to the `mob` models in the `party` and `partykit` packages. But instead of learning splits from the data, I want to specify the splits in advance based on expert opinion, so that I obtain a more nicely structured and interpretable model. Can any existing tools do this in a slick way?

To fit the model, you partition data into $n$ sets according to the value of some factor $X$ with $n$ levels. You then fit some classical regression model, say Cox regression, to each subset. To predict on a new observation, you first determine which set your new observation belongs to, then feed it to the appropriate regression model.

I suppose I could rig this up with S3 without too much trouble, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly doable but not in a few lines of code. My recommendation of what to do depends a little bit on what you want to do with it. If you just want to have a way to fit and predict the model, I would probably do something simpler. If you additionally want visualizations like for `mob()` then it might be worth the effort to mimic a `modelparty` S3 object from `partykit`. (Doing it in `party` with its S4 classes would be very, very cumbersome...even for myself :-))

Quick & dirty: If you *know* the correct subgroups, I would simply set up a new factor coding the segments, say:

```
d$seg <- ifelse(d$x1 > 0, ifelse(d$x2 == "a", 1, 2), 3)
    d$seg <- factor(d$seg)
```

for creating a factor `seg` with three levels that depend on the interaction of variables `x1` and `x2`. With these you can easily fit your segmented model, e.g.,

```
m <- lm(y ~ seg * x)
```

or

```
m <- lm(y ~ seg / x)
```

for different codings of the coefficients. And then for out-of-sample predictions you first need to set up the `seg` factor on the new data (as above) and then call `predict(m, ...)`. Not very elegant but should be simple and fast enough.

Via `partykit`: If you want to set up a `modelparty` object, I would recommend to first call `mob()` (or `lmtree()` or so) to create a tree based on the right variables. It can have just a single split but it would already have the correct `terms` and `model.frame` etc. Subsequently, you could replace the `$node` with your pre-specified tree. See `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` on how to do so. The `$info` elements need to contain the fitted models, parameters, etc. The resulting object will be nice once you have it...but the way to get it is not easy or elegant either.